# loadVideoById EndSeconds doesn't work?

Tags: jquery, youtube-api

how to set the end seconds using loadVideoById() ? i try

```
loadVideoById("video_id","start_time","end_time","quality")
```

but no results.. any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't call any of the methods on the YT.Player object (including `loadVideoById`) as long as `onPlayerReady` hasn't been called.

Doing a check `if(player) {...}` isn't sufficient, the `Player` object will be created and some properties will already be available in out without the methods you need being available.

Comment: I have the full working script, the player runs correctly, i'v defined the start time but not the end time because when i set it the player doesn't load.. :|